# Why would one need "async" support for MS Unit Test if Task.Result can be used?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await

I'm a bit puzzled here...I have a test method which does a call to an async method and I changed the signature to `async Task`. Works.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestIt()
{
  bool result = await service.SomethingAsync();
  Assert(result);
}
```

Now I read all over the web that support for async is required in unit tests and is now also in NUnit. But why is that so important? I can write the test like this, using the `Result` property which will wait for `Task` completion:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestIt()
{
  bool result = service.SomethingAsync().Result;
  Assert(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Result` has an unfortunate side effect of wrapping all exceptions in `AggregateException`. This makes testing the error path much more painful.

But even if you decide you could live with that, you still have the problem of calling multiple `async` methods within a single test; i.e., if your test setup also requires `async` work. To do it in a blocking way, you'd have to either refactor your test method into a separate `async` method, or wrap it in an `async` delegate and either execute it directly or toss it into `Task.Run`. Not impossible, but not convenient either.

Finally, there's the problem of `async` components that assume a one-thread-at-a-time context. Examples include ViewModels and WebAPI/MVC controllers. At that level, those components often assume that they don't need to synchronize access to asynchronously shared data because they're never executed in a free-threaded context. Until you unit test, that is. The common approach is to give those unit tests a single-threaded context, e.g., installing a `Dispatcher` on the unit test thread. In that case, a `Result` will deadlock. There are ways around this but, again, it's not convenient to write that code.

The bottom line is that `async` unit tests don't make it *possible;* they make it *convenient.* And anything that encourages unit testing (especially for trickier things like `async`) is a good idea. :)

Comment: I do not understand the part with "multiple async methods within a single test": doesn't the Result approach execute the methods synchronously and hence, having multiple calls should not matter? I had exactly this case and the test method finished just fine.

Comment: @Krumelur: Yes, that's correct. I was getting ahead of myself; the multiple `async` calls would only be an issue in a one-thread-at-a-time context.